# Is $L=\{a^{i}b^{j}c^{k}\mid i\geq j\geq k\}  $ a context-free language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

The given language is $ L = \{ a^{i} b^{j} c^{k} \mid i \geq j \geq k \}  $

If yes can someone give its productions because I have tried a lot ....

The problem of course is to limit the value of b ....

I have tried to apply the pumping lemma for context-free grammar and I think it does satisfy it... Can someone verify this...

Thanks a lot ..

PS :- It is **not** a homework...

Comment: Whatyou want to know if that set is a context-free *language*: you should edit your title so that it asks the correct question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed **not** a context free language.

Pick $z = a^{p}b^pc^p$

$vwx$ cannot contain a's, b's and c's. We pump the string depending on the string $vwx$ as follows:

1. There are no c's. Then we try pumping down to obtain the string $uv^0wx^0y$ to get $uwy$. This contains the same number of c's, but fewer a's or b's. Therefore it is not in $L$.
2. There are no b's but there are c's. Then we pump up to obtain the string $uv^2wx^2y$ to give us more c's than b's and this is not in $L$.
3. There are no b's but there are a's. Then we pump down to obtain the string $uwy$. This string contains the same number of b's but fewer c's, therefore this is not in $L$.
4. There are no a's. Then we pump up to obtain the string $uv^2wx^2y$ to give us more b's or more a's than there are c's, so this is not in $L$.

Since we can come up with a contradiction for any case, this language is not a CF language.

Comment: Note: I am presuming that $k \geq 0$

Comment: Yes that is true ... One follow up doubt though ... If I have something like i > j > k would it still not be a CFL ?

Comment: @user8250: yes, and we can confirm this with the same proof. ≥ is a more general case.